# A reflection based Object binder for java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I would like to automatically bind properties from a `java.util.Properties` instance to the fields in an object.

Preferable something like this:

```
Properties props = ... // has for instance the property "url=http://localhost:8080
MyType myType = ...
PropertiesBinder.bind(props, myType);
assertEquals("http://localhost:8080", myType.getUrl());
```

It is not that hard to roll your own, but i wonder if someone already has done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BeanUtils.populate(object, map)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29)

`Properties extends Hashtable implements Map`, so you can use it in the above method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set String values, this will do (you do not need a third party library):

```
public static void bind(Properties props, Object obj) throws Exception {
    Field field;
    Class<?> cLass = obj.getClass();
    for (String prop : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
        try {
            field = cLass.getDeclaredField(prop);
            if (field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                if (!field.isAccessible())
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(obj, props.get(prop));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            System.err.println("no luck");
        }
    }
}
```

For advanced things, I'd suggest the preferences API, guice, spring, pico container, or a tool that I maintain by name [InPUT](https://github.com/feldob/InPUT).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing configuration type things, take a look at [config-magic](https://github.com/brianm/config-magic) which allows you to use annotations to map configuration properties to bean getters.

Answer (score 0):

Property Binder: http://pholser.github.com/property-binder